# "a massive line’s worth of fans disappointed" meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning, reading-comprehension

> James also hinted last week at a possible appearance at a Blaze Pizza in Culver City with a tweet on Monday. But James never showed up, leaving **a massive line’s worth of fans disappointed**. The mural was gone hours later. Other public institutions, like the famous Santa Monica pier Ferris wheel, have shown their excitement through a variety of displays. So to see the fans positively react to the four-time MVP must have been a welcome sign for him.

I don't quite understand **a massive line’s worth of fans disappointed** in this context. I can understand if the sentence have written as **a massive line of fans disappointed**. I don't know why **worth** is added?

The [full source](https://sports.yahoo.com/lebron-james-sporting-lakers-shorts-receives-standing-ovation-upon-arrival-summer-league-204624830.html?guccounter=1).

Comment: The linked story has been edited to "a massive line of fans".  So I guess the editors decided that "worth" was unnecessary in the same way you did.

Comment: @JohnFeltz this is interesting. Do you have any ideas why *worth* is used from a native speaker's perspective? I am eager to know that. Thanks!

Comment: "a massive line" = there was literally a line; "a massive line's worth" = there were enough people to form a massive line, but they weren't actually standing in line.  You could use this expression as, for example, "an arena's worth of people" = enough people to fill an arena, but you didn't actually have an arena to put them in.

Comment: @JohnFeltz oh, I see it. So it seems that the author thought it should be a literal massive line in this case. That's why he edited to *a massive line of fans*. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the distinction given by "worth"